# How would I remove white space between images using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a small personal project, and for the main page, it's going to be several images, one after another, each the size of the page.

I'm try to get rid of this type of spacing:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you cut and paste your HTML (and CSS)?  That will show how you laid it out, what the problem is and allow another dev to post a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `display: block` for each `img`. Example in the snippet below. `height` is set just so the image isn't too big.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  height: 150px;  
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/B5vX1kN.jpg"/>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/KYXOUfE.png"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must set in style as:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should post your CSS and HTML code otherwise it is quite hard fix that problem.

A possible solution is

```
img{border:0;}
```

or

```
img {display: block;}
```